# Tag request: Nokia

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The Nokia smartphones have come to the market, and a lot of people are using them.

In Android Enthusiasts SE, we are finding questions on Nokia smartphones. [This search](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nokia) reveals the questions that are on Nokia smartphones.

So, it is quite evident that a tag for Nokia is needed. I believe that rather than making tags for each version of Nokia smartphones, firstly we should make a tag on Nokia itself: [nokia](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia), like there is one on Samsung: [samsung](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung). Later, we can go forth and make tags on the popular versions.

Comment: As you have the [required 300 rep](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) I'd say go ahead – sounds reasonable, as we also have tags for other manufacturers. But as with those, this should be a fallback only if there's no more (device) specific tag, so you might wish to go for those as well (make sure to skip the non-Android devices ;) For a slimmer list, [here's an adjusted search](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nokia+is%3Aq+duplicate%3Ano+closed%3Ano). Didn't filter out "invalid devices" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to inform everyone that I've created tags the following tags:

[nokia-x](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-x)
[nokia-xl](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-xl)
[nokia-x-plus](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-x-plus)
[nokia-2](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-2)
[nokia-3](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-3)
[nokia-5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-5)
[nokia-6](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-6)

The [nokia](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia) was supposed to be created so that when a question is on a new model of Nokia smartphones, there is at least one tag present. But with advice from @Izzy, I didn't create it at the end, keeping in mind that some or the other high reputation users or moderator would create the required tag, if they happen to come across the question.

### Update: (dated January 23, 2018)

@NVZ has added the tag [nokia-8](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-8).

Answer (score 2):

Meh. Manufacturer tags like that get abused. Better to have tags for individual models.

What sort of questions would merit a [nokia](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia) tag?