# Please add a tag for Nokia-9

Tags: discussion, tags

As of this writing, there are 16 specific model tags for Nokia, in addition to [the general Nokia tag](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2381/tag-request-nokia).

Since those tags stopped at `nokia-8`, can you please add one for [nokia-9](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-9)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nokia-9](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-9) has been added to [How to enable an "Always on Display" mode in Nokia 9 for JUST notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230890/how-to-enable-an-always-on-display-mode-in-nokia-9-for-just-notifications), assuming if this issue is specific to Nokia 9.

There are no other questions that I found to be specific for Nokia 9. Unless [How to force a smartphone to do update?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229468/how-to-force-a-smartphone-to-do-update), is a specific issue to Nokia 9, feel free to tag it. Otherwise, we prefer to let it tagged with the general [nokia](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia) if it's Nokia policy, or remove the tag altogether if it's a known issue for multiple brands.

Comment: "How to" is indeed specific so I've updated it too. By nature people can usually testify only about the current model they have.